# Component to return something different depending on props

Tags: reactjs

I know it may be a simple question, but I have a little problem in React, what condition to use so that when useFor is Card to return the first div, and when useFor is Details to return the second one.

```
const YoutubeEmbed = ({ embedId, useFor }) => (
  <>
    {useFor === "Card"}
    <>
      <div>
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
    </>
    {useFor === "Details"}
    <>
      <div className="video-responsive">
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
    </>

  </>
);

YoutubeEmbed.propTypes = {
  embedId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  useFor: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html
You can use conditional render to render specific parts:

```
const YoutubeEmbed = ({ embedId, useFor }) => (
  <>
    {useFor === 'Card' && (
      <>
        <div>
          <iframe
            src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
            allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            title="Embedded youtube"
          />
        </div>
      </>
    )}
    {useFor === 'Details' && (
      <>
        <div className="video-responsive">
          <iframe
            src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
            allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            title="Embedded youtube"
          />
        </div>
      </>
    )}
  </>
)

YoutubeEmbed.propTypes = {
  embedId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  useFor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using regular conditions?

```
const YoutubeEmbed = ({ embedId, useFor }) => {
    if (useFor === "Card") {
        return <div>
            <iframe
                src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
                allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                title="Embedded youtube"
            />
        </div>;
    }

    if (useFor === "Details") {
        return <div className="video-responsive">
            <iframe
                src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
                allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                title="Embedded youtube"
            />
        </div>;
    }
    
    return null;
}

YoutubeEmbed.propTypes = {
    embedId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    useFor: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator?retiredLocale=vi) for render with that condition in React:

```
const YoutubeEmbed = ({ embedId, useFor }) => (
  <>
    {useFor === "Card" ? <>
      <div>
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
    </>
    : useFor === "Details" ? <>
      <div className="video-responsive">
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
    </> : null
   }
</>
);

YoutubeEmbed.propTypes = {
  embedId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  useFor: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone, I just didn't know what to google, I actually used it like this, so that I do not repeat the same code twice.

```
const YoutubeEmbed = ({ embedId, useFor }) => (
      <div className={useFor === 'Card' ? "" : "video-responsive"}>
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use condition to return content based on useFor

```
const YoutubeEmbed = ({ embedId, useFor }) => {
    if (useFor === "Card"){
     return <div>
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
    }else if(useFor === "Details"){
      return <div className="video-responsive">
        <iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          title="Embedded youtube"
        />
      </div>
  }
  return null // if condition is not satisfied
};

YoutubeEmbed.propTypes = {
  embedId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  useFor: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```